# Jquery/CSS carousel/slider effect on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set up 3 divs, one on the left and two on the right on top of each other.

I want the 'onclick' to make the div on the left slide out from the left
and one of divs on the right-top to go up and the one on the right-bottom to slide in from the right.

After that animations are finished I want the next time I press the 'onclick' button to do the same to the next divs *(with different content)* to come in from the points the previous divs came.

I've managed to change the background color of the div's but not the content and animations.

This is what I've gotten so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#next').click(function(){
    if ($('.active').next('.case').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .next('.case')
                    .addClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('#prev').click(function(){
    if ($('.active').prev('.case').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .prev('.case')
                    .addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,body,section{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#next,#prev{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:101;
}

#next{
  right:0px;
}

#prev{
  left:0px;
}

#t1{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:43%;
  background-color: #c92639;
      position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
  
  
}

#logo >h1{
 color: white;
}

#logo >h3{
     width: 58%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
#t2,#t3{
height: 50%;
    width: 57%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#t3{
      position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
   background-color: #c8c8c8;
}
#t2{
 background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#t2 >img{
 margin-top: 11%;
}

#logo{
 margin-top: 40%;
}

#t3>ul{
 display: inline-table;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

#t3>ul>li{
 display: inline-table;
 width: 33%;

}

#t3>ul>li>div>img{
 width: 53%;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

#home{
 display: none !important;
}

#circle1,#circle2,#circle3{
    border-radius: 128px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

#circle1{
 background: #32325f;
}

#circle2{
 background: white;
}

#circle3{
 background: #ef9d34;
}

.active{
  display:initial !important;
  z-index:100;
  
}

#case{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:99;
}

.stern1{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="next">
  <h1>next</h1>
</div>
<div id="prev">
  <h1>prev</h1>
</div>

<div id="case" class="case active">
<div id="t1" class="tcee1">
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/cee.png" id="cee">
            <div id="underline"></div>
            <br>
            <h1>BRINGING AN OFFLINE ENCOUNTER TO AN ONLINE RELATION</h1><br>
            <h3>Every day Cee-Platform helps their customers to build a bridge between their offline and online marketing challenges.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="t2" class="case tcee2">
        <img src="img/ceedev.png">
    </div>
    <div id="t3" class="tcee3">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="circle1">
                <img src="img/computer.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Responsiv</h2><br>
                <p>My expierences with developing websites has learned me to make them structualy responsive from the ground up making it accesible for all platforms</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="circle2">
                <img src="img/g.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>SEO</h2><br>
                <p>Optimizing your website to result with high results on googles googles list</p>            
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="circle3">
                <img src="img/hand.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Storytelling</h2><br>
                <p>With every website you want to tell a story, it doens't matter if you want to tell your visitor how aswesome your compeny or how important your goal is. I'll make it the best one out there</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="case" class="case">
<div id="t1" class="tstern1" style="background:blue;">
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/cee.png" id="cee">
            <div id="underline"></div>
            <br>
            <h1>BRINGING AN OFFLINE ENCOUNTER TO AN ONLINE RELATION</h1><br>
            <h3>Every day Cee-Platform helps their customers to build a bridge between their offline and online marketing challenges.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="t2" class="tstern2">
        <img src="img/ceedev.png">
    </div>
    <div id="t3" class="tstern3">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="circle1">
                <img src="img/computer.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Responsiv</h2><br>
                <p>My expierences with developing websites has learned me to make them structualy responsive from the ground up making it accesible for all platforms</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="circle2">
                <img src="img/g.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>SEO</h2><br>
                <p>Optimizing your website to result with high results on googles googles list</p>            
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="circle3">
                <img src="img/hand.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Storytelling</h2><br>
                <p>With every website you want to tell a story, it doens't matter if you want to tell your visitor how aswesome your compeny or how important your goal is. I'll make it the best one out there</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="case" class="case">
<div id="t1" class="tstern1" style="background:black;">
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/cee.png" id="cee">
            <div id="underline"></div>
            <br>
            <h1>BRINGING AN OFFLINE ENCOUNTER TO AN ONLINE RELATION</h1><br>
            <h3>Every day Cee-Platform helps their customers to build a bridge between their offline and online marketing challenges.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="t2" class="tstern2">
        <img src="img/ceedev.png">
    </div>
    <div id="t3" class="tstern3">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id="circle1">
                <img src="img/computer.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Responsiv</h2><br>
                <p>My expierences with developing websites has learned me to make them structualy responsive from the ground up making it accesible for all platforms</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="circle2">
                <img src="img/g.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>SEO</h2><br>
                <p>Optimizing your website to result with high results on googles googles list</p>            
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="circle3">
                <img src="img/hand.png">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="underline"></div>
                <h2>Storytelling</h2><br>
                <p>With every website you want to tell a story, it doens't matter if you want to tell your visitor how aswesome your compeny or how important your goal is. I'll make it the best one out there</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What part doesn't work? Please be more specific

Comment: to start with passing on the active class to the next div, but i also want to pass it on to the previous. Only i don't have any notion of how

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have a look at this simple tutorial, its worked fine for me and you can add / improve it as well.

[simple javascript slideshow](https://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-simple-javascript-slideshow-without-jquery/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes